# Understanding CPU steal time in cloud

Tags: virtualization, performance, performance-monitoring

I am trying to understand about CPU steal time. This article is the top result:

https://scoutapm.com/blog/understanding-cpu-steal-time-when-should-you-be-worried

To be honest, I do not understand the ticket booth analogy. However, the concept of CPU time taken by other guest VMs on the host seems easy to understand.

What I don't understand is the two possible causes:

1. You need a larger VM with more CPU resources (you are the problem).
2. The physical server is over-sold and the virtual machines are aggressively competing for resources (you are not the problem).

For point 1, it further says

```
Has %st (CPU Steal Time Percentage) increased on every virtual server? 
This means your virtual machines are using more CPU. You need to increase 
the CPU resources for your VMs.
```

If VM is showing high amount of steal time, how can my VM be the problem? My VM has its CPU cycles taken and allocated elsewhere. Why it is my VM's fault? Is my VM stealing its own CPU? Can someone explain?

Also, if a VM is showing CPU steal time. Does it mean some other VM is would be showing negative CPU steal time because it is stealing other VMs' CPU?

Comment: What is the business related issue in here? What are you trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if a VM is showing CPU steal time, does it mean some other VM is would be showing negative CPU steal time because it is stealing other VMs' CPU?

***Steal time*** is the ***percentage*** of time the virtual machine process is (involuntary) waiting on the physical CPU for its CPU time.  That means there is no negative steal time, the range starts at <kbd>0 %</kbd> and the maximum is <kbd>100 %</kbd>

A VM that doesn't show steal time simply gets all the CPU  resources it needs  when it requests them. That VM doesn't get more *"more than it's (fair) share"*, not more than is paid for and isn't *"stealing your CPU"* cycles,  it simply doesn't spend time waiting before it gets allocated the CPU time it needs.

---

> What I don't understand is the two possible causes:
>
> - You need a larger VM with more CPU resources (you are the problem).
> - The physical server is over-sold and the virtual machines are
>   aggressively competing for resources (you are not the problem).

But you can be both the "victim" as well as part of the problem at the same time.

As a rule of thumb steal time cannot occur without a provider using CPU over-provisioning and selling more vCPU's to customers than the hypervisor has actual CPU cores.

The core concept is that by mixing the different workloads of different customers on a providers platform, the providers implicitly also (hope to) ensure that the peak demands of one customer will coincide with lower resource requirements from another customer at that point in time. And although peaks and dips won't completely average out, everybody gets their fair share and most if not all the resources when they need them and everybody remains more or less happy.

As the customer you benefit because that usually translates to much lower prices than paying for guaranteed resources.

But ***that only works when your workload doesn't require guaranteed and continuous  resources***. Your workloads most ***balance peak loads with longer times where you system sits mostly idle***. (And the same goes for the workloads of other customers.)

When your VM is undersized or overloaded and vCPU utilisation remains close to or at 100% for longer times, then the balance can become skewed and your VM doesn't offset its CPU demands with enough idle time (at the times that other customers have their peak loads) to ensure an even and fair balance.   Your system thus contributes and is part of the problem of increased resource contention and your system will also see more steal time.

When you increase the size of your VM, there will be more times that your system is partly idle and fewer times that it need all the assigned resources and there is a lower chance that it wil have to spend in involuntary wait.

Comment: However, if it causes trouble or headaches, I suggest looking for another host, IMHO.

Comment: Often powering your instance off and launching a new one will get the scheduler to launch it on a different hypervisor with less noisy neighbors

Comment: seems that android cut hoster down to host, damit ;)